# Joining email and dates in different ranges in SAS

Tags: mapping, sas

I have a communication log, ComLog, in SAS that looks like this

```
data ComLog;
   input mail $ SendDate:date.; 
   format SendDate date.; 
   cards; 
A@a     27Jan2013 1
A@a     29Jan2013 2
B@b     1Mar2013  3
C@c     3Mar2013  4
;;;;
run;
```

I also send some emails through an external system where I am trying to mapp whether the receiver opened the email. The file BackToComLog looks like this,

```
data BackToComLog;
   input mail $ ReadDate:date.; 
   format ReadDate date.; 
   cards; 
A@a     28Jan2013 
A@a     30Jan2013 
B@b     2Mar2013 
C@c     3Mar2013 .
;;;;
run;
```

Now, I am trying to left join the BackToCoMLog back to ComLog.  My final file should look like this

```
Mail SendDate OpenDate 
A@a     27Jan  28Jan
A@a     29Jan  30Jan
B@b     1Mar   2Mar
C@c     3Mar   3Mar
```

I have tried doiong this in a data step like this,

```
proc sort data=ComLog;
by mail SendDate;
run;

proc sort data=BackToComLog;
by mail ReadDate;
run;


 data want;
  do until (last.mail);
merge ComLog BackToComLog;
by mail;
if first.mail or (range(OpenDate, SendDate) > range(ReadDate, SendDate)) then OpenDate =     ReadDate;
end;
format OpenDate date9.;
drop ReadDate;
run;
```

That takes me a bit further, but my final files ends up like this,

```
   mail  SenDate   OpenDate
   A@a  29JAN13 28JAN2013
   B@b  01MAR13 02MAR2013
   C@c  03MAR13 03MAR2013
```

Thus, my A@a for 27Jan2013 is not in the final file, and the dates got mixed as well. I need the code to be able to take care of the same mail after each other with different dates.

Comment: I think that your example data is too 'clean'.  What happens if both A@a emails are opened on 31 Jan?  Or moreover if there is _one_ A@a OpenDate which is 31Jan?  Which is it applied to, 28Jan or 30Jan mailing?  The problem as stated above is not difficult, but a more realistic problem is much more complex with the limited information provided here.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE result_table as
SELECT *
FROM ComLog AS t1
LEFT JOIN BackToComLog AS t2 ON t1.Mail = t2.Mail
WHERE t1.SenDate < t2.OpenDate
;
QUIT;
```